# How to include header file if function declared and defined in different places?

Tags: c, header-files, turbo-c

```
main.c    headers
             |
      ________________
     |                |
  utils.h           utils
                      |
                     sum.c
```

I have the given hierarchy. Now I need to call sum function (which is declared in utils.h file but defined in sum.c file ) in main.c

What I should include in main.c, utils.h and sum.h

How I should write code? I am actually working on a C game project and I required such a structure to deal with it at ease

main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "headers/utils.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%d", sum(3,4));
    return 0;
}
```

utils.h file

```
#ifndef _headers_utils_h
#define _headers_utils_h
int sum(int, int);
#endif
```

sum.c file

```
#include "../utils.h"

int sum(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Expected output: 7

Comment: First off, I would ask myself why are there `.c` files in a folder called `headers`...

Comment: Your code seems working with GCC. What is your question? If your purpose is not to ask something but to share your knowledge, please separate it to question and answer. By the way, you mean `sum.c` by `sum.h`, right?

Comment: So you want to do that. I assume it means that it does not work as expected. How so? What happens unexpectedly? What should happen but does not? Just for completeness, please add detailed information on how you build and call (or attempt to). E.g. explain how exactly you achieve that both .c files are compiled and the result linked together to make an executable. Show the commandline you use to do that, your makefile or the configuration for those things in your IDE.

Comment: **Again, what is your question?** You have answered both questions (in the title and the text) yourself. The sources shown have no obvious errors.

Comment: Actually, no problem I got it cleared. I was actually not changing the directory path for linking files correctly